# Creating a "contact us" page using html

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a link which a user can click, that then redirects them to their email system allowing them to directly email a certain address. I'm not entirely sure how I would go about doing so.

If anyone could give me some tips that would be great, thanks.

Comment: I'm having a really hard time finding a duplicate for this because it is *so* massively underresearched that I don't think anyone has bothered to ask this before.

Comment: @L_Church — There is no need to involve anything other than HTML for this.

Comment: not a thing of need its just background checks to see if hes done any of it... just a google away so i assumed too quick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hi i think this should work

```
<a href="mailto:someone@yoursite.com?subject=Mail from Our Site">Email Us</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a mailto link:
`<a href="mailto:your_email_address">Send an Email </a>`

Answer (score 1):

**You can use Mailto Links**
*What is mailto link*

- Mailto link is a type of HTML link that activates the default mail client on 
  the computer for sending an e-mail.
- The web browser requires a default e-mail client software installed on his 
  computer in order to activate the e-mail client.
- If you have Microsoft Outlook, for example as your default mail client, 
  pressing a mailto link will open a new mail window.

*Basic*

Open default mail program, create new message with the TO field already filled out.

```
<a href="mailto:someone@yoursite.com">Email Us</a>
```

*Adding a subject*

Open default mail program, create new message with the TO and SUBJECT field already filled out. Essentially we are adding the parameter subject to the href value.

```
<a href="mailto:someone@yoursite.com?subject=Mail from Our Site">Email Us</a>
```

*Adding CC and BCC*

Open default mail program, create new message with the TO, SUBJECT, CC, and BCC field already filled out. Essentially we are adding the parameters cc and bcc to the href value.

Also note that you add multiple values to CC and BCC by comma separating them.

```
<a href="mailto:someone@yoursite.com?cc=someoneelse@theirsite.com, another@thatsite.com, me@mysite.com&bcc=lastperson@theirsite.com&subject=Big%20News">Email Us</a>
```

*Adding Body Text*

```
<a href="mailto:someone@yoursite.com?cc=someoneelse@theirsite.com, another@thatsite.com, me@mysite.com&bcc=lastperson@theirsite.com&subject=Big%20News&body=Body-goes-here">Email Us</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

**summary**
You want a front end contact us page
No forms, in which the user can click a link to open up the relevant program to use

**solution**
Use protocols in your href attribute of an anchor tag

Example

```
<a href="tel:001267555555">Call us</a>
```

The tel protocol will open a program relevant for making phone calls, ie skype on a desktop or the call screen on a mobile phone

Or

```
<a href="mailto:sombody@website.co.uk">email us</a>
```

Will open an email programme like outlook and show a window with the email address in the to field

For more information on href protocols for anchor tags visit

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_anchor_protocol.asp